# mysql dynamically add unique constraint

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table which has five location columns (Los Angeles, New York, etc.) which have a column value of a neighborhood, a code which refers to the location (LA, NY, etc), and a userID. The code and userID are always present- and at least one of the location columns has a value.

Ideally, I'd like to normalize this table- but as a short-term solution, I'd like to add a constraint which says:

"ensure a unique combination of userID, code, and location."

For instance:

**row1**: has userID=1, code=NY, New York=Brooklyn, Los Angeles=Chinatown

**row2**: has userID=1, code=NY, New York=West Side, Los Angeles=Chinatown

The second row should be allowed to insert, since the New York neighborhood is different.

I've tried regular constraints:

ALTER TABLE locations ADD UNIQUE `location`(`user_id`, `code`, `new_york`);

ALTER TABLE locations ADD UNIQUE `location`(`user_id`, `code`, `los_angeles`);

but the second row doesn't insert because the second constraint above stops it.

Short of normalizing the table, what is the best option to create this constraint?

Comment: Wouldn't creating a unique constraint on user_id, code and all location columns solve your issue? "ALTER TABLE locations ADD UNIQUE location(user_id, code, new_york, los_angeles, ...);"

Comment: @jedrzej.kurylo That should work, as long as he is using NULL in the "other" location columns; if he is using something like '' (empty string), or a hard-coded string constant like '[IRRELEVANT]' that may be his problem now.

Answer (score -1):

Create a table with the cities 
id|city 
 1|New York 
 2|Los Angeles 
..|.. 

And alter table location adding a foreign key to this table and set primary key (id, code, city)

id|code|city 
1 |345 |1  <- This is NY 
1 |123 |1 
..|..  |..

Comment: I don't see how that would fix the unique constraint issue.